# Optimizing Nested For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I'm working on a performance-intensive library and wanted to see if anyone had some ideas on how to improve the performance of this method which converts our models to a js object.

You'll see below that I've tried to employ a couple of optimization techniques based on my reading:

- Use straight for loops to iterate objects, arrays
- Cache nested objects to avoid excessive lookups (`field = fields[i]`, etc).

**Here's the method I'm trying to further optimize:**

```
toObject: function() {

  var i, l, fields, field, schema, obj = {};

  for(i = 0, fields = Object.keys(this._schema), l = fields.length; i < l; i++) {

    field = fields[i], schema = this._schema[field];

    if(!this._data.hasOwnProperty(field) || (schema.hasOwnProperty('output') && !schema[field].output)) {
      continue;
    }

    if(schema.hasOwnProperty('collection')) {

      obj[field] = [];

      schema.collection.instances.forEach(function (mdl) {
        obj[field].push(mdl.toObject());
      });
    }

    obj[field] = schema.hasOwnProperty('processOut') ? schema.processOut.call(this, this._data[field]) : this._data[field];
  }

  return obj;
}
```

In particular, I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize:

```
schema.collection.instances.forEach(function (mdl) {
  obj[field].push(mdl.toObject());
});
```

If I'm not mistaken, the function within the forEach is being created on each iteration. I was going to try and move it out of the main for loop, but then I lose access to `field` which I need to set the property key on `obj`.

I also thought about turning this into another for/loop, but then I'd have to create another set of variables like so:

```
// these vars would be init'd at the top of toObject or 
// maybe it makes sense to put them within the parent 
// for loop to avoid the additional scope lookup?
var x, xl;

for(x = 0, xl = schema.collection.instances.length; x < xl; x++) {
  obj[field].push(schema.collection.instances[x].toObject());
}
```

This just looks a little ugly, though, to be honest - this is a situation where we are collectively willing to forgo a *little* readability for performance.

I realize these may be minor micro-optimizations, but they've been shown to add up in my anecdotal experience when modeling several thousands of objects.

Comment: I guess instead of `forEach` you could use `map`.

Comment: @elclanrs I've seen many a jsperf test showing how slow map is.

Comment: @JacobMattison not sure I follow. I can't control what get's passed to a forEach function - it's (item, index, array).

Comment: Are you having performance issues at this point? If not I would worry about correctness and readability first. `map` is ok.

Comment: 100% in agreement with  @elclanrs. There comes a point when optimization becomes micro-optimization, which is rarely necessary except in the case of definite bottle-necks.

Comment: Yes, I am having performance issues. This is part of a rewrite to try and squeeze as much performance improvements as we can into the refactor. Any ms shaved will be multiplied by the 10's of thousands of objects that must run through this.

Comment: @doremi: Then maybe avoid the `forEach` loop with its many calls. Also, you should cache `hasOwnProperty.call` which you're looking up very often.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop you have suggested is about as good as you're going to get. A couple optimizations you could take would be to avoid property lookups:

```
var objval = obj[field],
    instances = schema.collection.instances;
for(x = 0, xl = instances.length; x < xl; ++x) {
  objval.push(instances[x].toObject());
}
```

On a semi-related note, `hasOwnProperty()` does cause a signficant performance hit (compared to something simpler like `field !== undefined`).

Comment: Because the size of the array is known he can use `new Array(instances.length)`, instead of `[]` and `push`

Comment: Last I benchmarked, using `[]` and `push()` was actually faster in the version of v8 that node (at least v0.10.x) uses.

Comment: Hopefully I didn't benchmark wrong: http://jsperf.com/array-initialization-push-vs-indexer Current browsers agree that `[i]=x` is faster than `push(x)` and `new Array(n)` is faster than `[]` everywhere except Edge (which disguises itself as Chrome 46). You're welcome